# Using jQuery UI Draggable with scrollbar problems?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="scroll"> 
  <div class="foo">foo1</div>
  <div class="foo">foo2</div>
  ....
  <div class="foo">foo8</div>
</div>

<div id="to_drop">
  DROP HERE!!!
</div>
```

with this CSS code:

```
  #scroll
  {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

and I the following Javascript/jQuery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function ()
  {
    $('.foo').draggable();
  });
```

The **problem** is that although `.foo` elements are `draggable`, they can only be dragged inside the `#scroll div`. Is there a way to avoid this? (check [here](http://dirib.com/blink/foo.html) for an example)

Because I would like for a user to be able to drag an element from the `#scroll` and when doing so  the scrolling won't work (if he is dragging a `.foo` inside the `#scroll`, the scrollbar won't move, scrollbar should work only when user clicks with his/her mouse on the scrollbar and moves it), and be able to drop it at `#to_drop`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original element is limited to the bounds of its parent because of the `overflow: auto` style.

You can work around the problem with a `clone` [helper](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-helper):

```
$('.foo').draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SswbX/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".foo" ).draggable({ containment: 'window' });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately I have still the same problem. Have a look here:  http://dirib.com/blink/foo.html

Comment: containment: 'document' then?

Comment: hmmpf.. Kinda figured it would http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc4/demos/draggable/containment.html Ill follow this topic

Comment: Ah you need to add a helper: clone